# old opened files still listed by RHEL 5.5 Tikanga

Tags: linux, rhel, ls

I have a RHEL 5.5 Tikanga distribution installed for training purpose.
For an unknown reason, when I list the content of a directory, it also shows me the files opened in the past, which are no more exists in my directory.

Can anyone tells me how to solve this?

To reproduce it, just:

1. create 2 files in a directory
2. open one of them with GEDIT
3. close GEDIT
4. delete the file previously opened in GEDIT
5. perform a ls command.

As result, it is displayed the current file but also the previously deleted file, ended with ~ (as it is still there, opened).

Comment: It's not the previously deleted file, it's a backup made by your editor.

Comment: And what can I do to not appear anymore when listing?

Comment: Um... Delete it?

Comment: hmmm, it worked from terminal but it drove me crazy because in File Browser, the backup were not displayed

Comment: File managers have a bad habit of thinking they know better than you and hiding things, yes.

Comment: @jww: the basic behavior of the question was observed when I try to write come code in shall script. In order to not flood the page with unnecessary lines of code, I posted just the minimum steps to reproduce.

Comment: "In order to not flood the page with unnecessary lines of code, I posted just the minimum steps to reproduce." - so the question becomes **non-programming**. There is nothing bad in such questions... They simply belongs to other SE site .